# Paginator shows weird result. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, kaminari

I'm using `kaminari` for pagination.
Then I have 3 models such as `User`, `Community`, and `Uniquecode`.

I'm facing the problem, in which the number of shown records varie(change) at each params[:page].

In addition, if I put `<% @uniquecode_count %>`, it returns '1'... 
Since there are 3 related records, it has to be '3', though.

This is really weird.  In my case. I have related 3 Uniquecode records.
As I did put `paginates_per 1` in Uniquecode model, it should show only 1 record at each page. However the result is

- At Page. 1  It shows 3 records
- At Page. 2  It shows 2 records
- At Page. 3  It shows 1 record

Why does do this? I never seen Kaminari doing this.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

I defined association like this

```
User has_many :communities
User has_many :uniquecodes

Community belongs_to :user
Community has_many :uniquecodes

Uniquecode belongs_to :user
Uniquecode belongs_to :community
```

**uniquecode model**

```
paginates_per 1
```

**controller**

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@uniquecodes = @user.uniquecodes.page(params[:page])
@uniquecodes_count = @uniquecodes.count
```

**view**

```
<%= paginate @uniquecodes, :window => 4 %>
<% @uniquecodes.recent.each do |uniquecode| %>   
    <%= render 'uniquecodes/uniquecode', :uniquecode => uniquecode %>
<% end %>

<% @uniquecode_count %>  => this shows '1'. It has to show '3' though.
```

Comment: Why is there are `recent` in `<% @uniquecodes.recent.each do |uniquecode| %> `?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should set a default order for your uniquecodes..?

Comment: I'm not using any order as you see here. all I have `scope :recent, lambda { |n = 10| includes(:user).where('users.deleted_at' => nil).order("users.last_active_at DESC").limit(n) }` in my uniquecode model. But I'm not using that here.

Comment: scope :recent, lambda { |n = 10| includes(:user).where('users.deleted_at' => nil).order("users.last_active_at DESC").limit(n).order("uniquecodes.created_at desc") }

Comment: Thanks but the same result:(

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
@uniquecodes = @user.uniquecodes.page(params[:page])
```

by

```
@uniquecodes = Kaminari.paginate_array(@user.uniquecodes).page(params[:page])
```